# Cant run this on python console but i can in the python shell

Tags: python, shell, console

I am new to python.

I wrote this script to help me perform some calculations:

```
print('Calc')

a= float(input('Insert a: '))
b= float(input('Insert b: '))
c= float(input('Insert c: '))

print('d:  ')
d= float((13+(1.2*a)-(19*b)))
print(d)

print('e: ')
e=float(-124+(1*c)+(-3*b)+(8.5*a)+(6.2*d))
print(e)

print('f: ')
f=float((b/50)*d)
print(f)

print('g: ')
g=float(d/a)
print(g)
```

It runs very well in python shell, but when I run it in the console it doesn't give me any output (yes he asks for the inputs, after I insert the inputs the console just shut downs), and I don't want to open the cal.py file every time in the shell. Its more practical to just click on it an let it run on the console

Do I have to add anything to that code so it can run on python console?

Comment: The window is just closing after the code finishes running.  You can add something like `wait = input('Press any key to exit')` to hold the window open at the end.

Comment: Put an `input("whatever")` in order to wait until the user inputs something. This will maintain the window open.

Comment: thank you man. It works, cant believe it was this easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the console remain opened by adding a dummy input prompt after the execution of the main code. Example:

```
input("Press enter to exit")
```

Comment: Thank you. I am very new to this "world", cant believe it was this easy.